# HTML Input of type text for passwords

Tags: secure-coding

A site (I won't name it) is using an input of type `text` for its password field in an HTML form. The `onfocus` method then changes those characters to dots.

Is there a security breach here ?

Or is it more secure than using an input of type `password` ?

Or is it just a lost opportunity to leverage existing code ?

Comment: If what u wrote is true, then user clicking outside password field would reveal the password.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Good point, I added that to my answer.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow The password doesn't show when exiting the field. There must be additional JavaScript to keep it in dot form. There was a lot of work that went into avoiding the "password" type apparently.

Comment: is this all across the site (account creation, password change, login) or just a subset of the password entry fields?

Comment: The only security benefit of using type password over type text is to prevent shoulder surfing as pointed out by S.L. Barth. Some mobile websites use text field for password to improve UX since risk of shoulder surfing is lower on a smaller display.

Comment: @Owen Account creation is not available because this is a site to store company information. Your company creates your account. The "password change form" uses the type "password".

Comment: I am not sure what year `type="password"` was drafted but was this website built before that? My only assumption for this design "choice" is that many users were complaining that they could not see their password as they typed and kept locking their accounts, cue upper management, and the poor web developer was coerced into throwing security practices out the window.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I did a little searching. `type="password"` has been around at least since [HTML version 2](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html.dtd), around 1995. I'm guessing this website is younger than that.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow In addition to preventing shoulder surfing, I was under the impression that certain web browsers will remember text inputs but can be configured to not remember inputs of type password

Comment: The site was designed in 2000.

Comment: Im sure that `type="password"` is older than JavaScript.

Comment: @QuectionOverflow in order to reveal password, there would have to be `onblur` event attached to undo effects of `onfocus` one.

Comment: BTW. HTML5 has `placeholder` attribute, i.e. text label that is displayed in text box (which applies to password box too) when user hasn't entered anything into it yet. I think the text box described in this question is a poor man's emulation of `placeholder`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a vulnerability. If users have JavaScript disabled, their passwords will not be changed to dots, and thus they are vulnerable to shoulder surfing.

As user @Question Overflow points out in their comment to your question, clicking outside the field would also display the password. Which means a co-worker could see the user's password by taking their mouse for a moment - even accidentally.

Comment: I just tested disabling JavaScript. Password is indeed clearly visible.

Comment: I don't see how is this a vulnerability (while JavaScript is on, that is). They're just using a custom input, and it still hides the password (even when the element loses focus, as the OP cleared up). It's redundant to make such a field, yes, but there's no vulnerability there.

Comment: In order to reveal password, there would have to be `onblur` event attached to undo effects of `onfocus` one. This doesn't happen by magic;)

Answer (score 3):

The site may be following the guidance in the article "[Stop Password Masking](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/stop-password-masking/)", posted by Jakob Nielsen on June 23, 2009.

> Summary: Usability suffers when users type in passwords and the only feedback they get is a row of bullets. Typically, masking passwords doesn't even increase security, but it does cost you business due to login failures.

Password masking addresses the shoulder surfing attack at a substantial cost in usability, especially among non-technical users who do not use a password manager. The site may have weighed the risk of shoulder surfing compared to other attacks on users' credentials and deemed it not worth the loss of usability. I've seen some other sites that use a JavaScript control to toggle the password field's `type` attribute between `"password"` and `"text"`, letting the user make his own tradeoff between usability and security against shoulder surfing.

The site in question is described as not *quite* following this advice. Perhaps the engineers were following this advice but then management requested that it be changed. Or perhaps they were trying to emulate the behavior of mobile devices that briefly show the last entered character in password fields.

Comment: Maybe, but then they are following Nielsen's advice wrongly as they are still masking the password... just in an unorthodox and vulnerable way.

Comment: While I don't believe this is what they are trying to achieve (because as S.L. Barth pointed out, they're still masking it), it's still interesting. +1.